# Sencha Touch - Nestedlist with iOS UITableView-like sections?

Tags: html, uitableview, extjs, sencha-touch, sections

Is it possible to use sections in Senchas Nestedlist? Currently i am dissecting a native iOS app and i wonder if the standard UITableView behavior is reproducable using Sencha/Html5/JS.

[image: Example]
<sub>(source: [icodeblog.com](http://www.icodeblog.com/wp-content/uploads/2010/12/Screen-shot-2010-12-10-at-3.02.09-PM.png))</sub>

The example screenshot above shows 3 sections: D, I, O

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's possible. You need to set to true this two list properties:

```
 grouped:true,
 indexBar: true,
```

Also your list's store must have `getGroupString` in order to know how to group the list items.

```
 getGroupString : function(record) {
      return record.get('firstName')[0];
 },
```

Here is live example: http://jsfiddle.net/sSyqF/16/